# Monomac packager creating folders

Tags: mono, monomac

I want to test deployment of my first mono mac app. (yay!)

But I need to create directories to save data in. But I would like to do it part of my install process on the mac. I have no clue how to make that part of the monomac packager???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to forgo creating these folders as a part of your install process and instead modify your application to check for them, and create them if they do not exist, because AFAIK, the current `mac-bundle` plugin to `mdtool` doest support that level of customization